# How to create a static grid of background images

Tags: css, background

Trying to create a page background in CSS that resembles a grid of assorted images, all cropped and resized to the same width and height.

Ideally, this background would pull random jpegs from a specific folder I create (assets/images/background_photos), and cascade them down/across the page within the borders of a pre-defined section.

Something like the attached image, but with multiple images instead of just the Star Wars poster repeated: 
[image]

```
.movie_poster_background{
    background-image: url("background_photos/star_wars.jpg");
    background-size: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: You're going to end up needing some javascript or other code besides just html and css to do the randomization part unfortunately.

Comment: You would either have to line them up one by one, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/198ufr0w/ or just make your background to start with, then you can repeat it to fill the screen and have different versions of the repeatable that you choose randomly

Answer (score 0):

You can consider multiple background then adjust the position of each image:

```css
.box{
    background-image: 
      url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069"),
      url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1065"),
      url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1066"),
      url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1067"),
      url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1068"),
      url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1062");
    background-size: 200px 200px;
    background-position:0 0,200px 0,400px 0,
                        0 200px,200px 200px,400px 200px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks like until I get a little more versed in Javascript, this solution works perfectly and looks beautiful.